# revalidating rails form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hotwire-rails

lets say I have two validations on rails model: it is necessary to fill both of them: name and title.

```rb
validate :name, presence: true
validate :title, presence true
```

when i submit blank form, error will be displayed. but when i fill only one and i do the submit, still both of the errors are displayed. Am I missing something? also, my form works in turbo frame, and when I fill both of the fields, the 'post' is created. and form disappears - this is ok. but if the error is displayed, the 'post' is created but form will not disappear. any help/info/guide welcomed.

as i have no idea what is going on

Comment: I assume that the error messages are created outside the turbo-frame and thus are not cleared. Could you sharethe code of your view?

Comment: thank you, i find out the culprit, i was using `turbo.replace` instead of `turbo.update`

Answer (score 0):

using

```rb
format.turbo_stream do
   render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update('form', partial: 'posts/form', locals: { post: @post })
end
```

instead of `turbo_stream.replace` solved the issue.